# What purpose of INT(some value) - some value in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I`ve tried to write TINYINT(1), TINYINT(2) and after the desc table; statement MYSQL shows that they are different, but when I try to put values in these fields, the actual size is the same - from -127 to 128 or if it would be UNSIGNED to 256. So what is the trick to use this, we can just write TINYINT at all?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

> MySQL supports an extension for optionally specifying the display width of integer data types in parentheses following the base keyword for the type. For example, INT(4) specifies an INT with a display width of four digits. This optional display width may be used by applications to display integer values having a width less than the width specified for the column by left-padding them with spaces. (That is, this width is present in the metadata returned with result sets. Whether it is used or not is up to the application.)